# player movement diagonally - too fast || NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, math

If I move the player right, left, up or down I move 5px in that direction.
But if I press down and right for example player is moving 5px right and 5px down which is around 7 pixels from the previous position instead 5px.

I can add next IF statement: if (up and down) then spdX and spdY = (maxSpd - maxSpd√2) / or simple -25% ?.

But I think already my code is bit messy...

[image]

Any nice solutions which are fast and looks simple? :)

That is my code:

```
self.updateSpd = function(){
    if(self.pressingRight){
        self.spdX = self.maxSpd;
        if(self.pressingShift && self.stamina > 0){
            self.spdX += self.maxRun;
            self.stamina --;
        }
    }
    else if(self.pressingLeft){
        self.spdX = -self.maxSpd;
        if(self.pressingShift && self.stamina > 0){
            self.spdX -= self.maxRun;
            self.stamina --;
        }
    }
    else{
        self.spdX = 0;
    }

    if(self.pressingUp){
        self.spdY = -self.maxSpd;
        if(self.pressingShift && self.stamina > 0){
            self.spdY -= self.maxRun;
            self.stamina --;
        }
    }
    else if(self.pressingDown){
        self.spdY = self.maxSpd;
        if(self.pressingShift && self.stamina > 0){
            self.spdY += self.maxRun;
            self.stamina --;
        }
    }
    else{
        self.spdY = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make variables for X and Y direction with values `-1`, `0`, `1`:

```
var dirX = -self.pressingLeft + self.pressingRight;
var dirY = -self.pressingUp + self.pressingDown;
```

Then adjust when moving diagonally:

```
if (dirX !== 0 && dirY !== 0) {
    dirX *= Math.SQRT1_2;
    dirY *= Math.SQRT1_2;
}
```

Then apply the rest:

```
var speed = self.maxSpd;

if (self.pressingShift && self.stamina > 0 && (dirX !== 0 || dirY !== 0)) {
    speed += self.maxRun;
    self.stamina--;
}

self.spdX = speed * dirX;
self.spdY = speed * dirY;
```

All told:

```
self.updateSpd = function () {
    var dirX = -self.pressingLeft + self.pressingRight;
    var dirY = -self.pressingUp + self.pressingDown;

    if (dirX !== 0 && dirY !== 0) {
        dirX *= Math.SQRT1_2;
        dirY *= Math.SQRT1_2;
    }

    var speed = self.maxSpd;

    if (self.pressingShift && self.stamina > 0 && (dirX !== 0 || dirY !== 0)) {
        speed += self.maxRun;
        self.stamina--;
    }

    self.spdX = speed * dirX;
    self.spdY = speed * dirY;
};
```

Or maybe:

```
self.updateSpd = function () {
    var dirX = -self.pressingLeft + self.pressingRight;
    var dirY = -self.pressingUp + self.pressingDown;

    var speed = self.maxSpd;

    if (self.pressingShift && self.stamina > 0 && (dirX !== 0 || dirY !== 0)) {
        speed += self.maxRun;
        self.stamina--;
    }

    if (dirX !== 0 && dirY !== 0) {
        speed *= Math.SQRT1_2;
    }

    self.spdX = speed * dirX;
    self.spdY = speed * dirY;
};
```

Note that this does behave differently from your original when both left and right are pressed (no movement, rather than moving right) or when both up and down are pressed (no movement, rather than moving up).

Comment: looks nice and clean and what is most important... I understand it :) 
I will try it evening after work and to avoid stops with up/down press I will close it in IF statement to walk right(right/left pressed) or down(up/down pressed. Thank you @Ryan !

Comment: I couldn't wait. Checked in work via TeamViewer and all works nice! ;) Thanks!

Comment: @BatOOn: Happy to help!